# Using MathML and JavaScript inside WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mathjax, mathml

I have the following webpage in HTML using MathML. In my Firefox, this displays a nice mathematical equation $a x^2 + b x + c$, as MathML should.

I figured I could now load this webpage into the WebBrowser of my Visual Studio 2015 WPF Application. However, the MathML does not render as expected. I suppose the WebBrowser component is not capable of dealing with MathML.

I have a second webpage using JavaScript, which I need for similar reasons. This, too, works in Firefox but not inside the WebBrowser of Visual Studio.

Any suggestions?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Title
</title>
</head>

<body>

MathML:

<br>

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<mrow>
<mi>a</mi>
<mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
<msup>
<mi>x</mi>
<mn>2</mn>
</msup>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>b</mi>
<mo>&InvisibleTimes; </mo>
<mi>x</mi>
<mo>+</mo>
<mi>c</mi>
</mrow>
</math>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it display correctly in Internet Explorer? Being Microsoft, I'm guessing that the web browser in Visual Studio is Internet Explorer in disguise.

Comment: Good point. Indeed it did not work in IE. I now used a different technique using CSS to display the Math. This seems to work, although I still need to click 'Allow blocked content' before it loads. I need to figure out how to avoid this.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathML is not yet supported by the WebBrowser in Visual Studio (probably IE). Math can be typeset using CSS and javascript. A webpage would then need to include

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

in order not to get the pop-up "Allow blocked content".